# How many possible five-digit integers are there that contain at least three distinct digits?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So on top of the property that there should be at least 3 distinct digits, there is the property that the first digit cannot be 0 (otherwise it would be a 4-digit number).

The way I've tried to tackle this is to let

A := {$x \in N : 10 000 \eqslantless  x \eqslantless 99999 $} 
(size = 90 000)

B := {$x \in N :$ x has at least 3 distinct digits}
(size = 60 * 10*10*10*9*8 = 4 320 000)

And then use the inclusion-exclusion principle but something is going wrong. Would appreciate some help on where I'm going wrong or a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think it's easier to count the counterexamples.  How many five digit integers are there?  How many use just a single digit?  How many use exactly two digts?

Comment: Out of curiosity is there any difference between $\eqslantless$ and $\leqslant$? I've never seen the line above the "less than" sign before.

Comment: @79037662  good point.  I had to click on "edit" just to see how to create that symbol.

Comment: @lulu Same, I found this old thread where the answerers were equally confused. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247719/meaning-of-geqslant-leqslant-eqslantgtr-eqslantless/247745

Comment: @lulu I hadn't thought about it like that - I'll give it a try.

Comment: @790307662 I don't know if there's a difference. I just used it because I'm inexperienced with Mathjax and it was the first symbol I found

Comment: @HarryVulvi  The only thing to worry about is the case where one of the two digits is $0$.  I suggest doing the two digits count first assuming that neither choice is $0$.  Then count the cases where one of them is $0$.